# How can I scale an object but only to one side and the end position after scaling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Now if I scale the x for example by 100 it will scale it both sides by 50.
But I want it to scale by 100 only to one side.

And after the scaling is finished, how can I get the last end position ? If for example I scaled the object on x by 100 and the starting position is 0,0,0 so the last position will be 100,0,0 ?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLinesAnimated : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform objectToScale;

    private void Start()
    {
       StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, new Vector3(100, 0, 0), 5));
    }

    bool isScaling = false;

    IEnumerator scaleOverTime(Transform objectToScale, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        //Make sure there is only one instance of this function running
        if (isScaling)
        {
            yield break; ///exit if this is still running
        }
        isScaling = true;

        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current scale of the object to be moved
        Vector3 startScaleSize = objectToScale.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            objectToScale.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }

        isScaling = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont. You scale and move it. eg say 0,0,0 is the middle, you scale it by 50 so it goes 50 all round, then move it so its where you wanted it, eg the -50 would be 0, so to achieve that you move it 50 to the right..

Answer (score 1):

So a simple solution would be to create this [Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjnoi.png) The startPoint and EndPoint both are just empty game objects, and the cube your 3d object.

Now scale the start point transform. Make sure the Startpoint and the Cube are the same size at the start (in this case both 1). When you scale the start point on the X axis, the cube will scale, and the end point will stay at the end. That way you can just get the position from that transform.

[Object at x = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5Wg.png)

[Object at x = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjLKy.png)